# Yii, PHPMailer Cannot be loaded

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

im trying for days many ways to send email from a local server using gmail.. i once made it with a yii extension but after a while, its not working, i tried to add the whole PHPMailer and make the mailing with the proper way.

this is my code:

```
static function gmail($email)
{
    $mail = new phpmailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "mail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password"; //best to keep this in your config file
    $mail->Subject = 'subject';
    $mail->Body = 'message';
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->send();
}
```

i downloaded the PHPMailer library from [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and extracted all to components folder.
The way how i added to config file is like this:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.components.PHPMailer.*'
),
```

on the first try i get this error `include(phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

**Update:** i forgot to say, the way how i access this function is this way `Mailer::gmail('$this->email');` where Mailer.php has the gmail function.

Comment: Watch your case. By looking in Github the class is named `PHPMailer` not `phpmailer`. Also I am not sure if Phpmailer is working out of the box together with Yii. But there is a handy extension right [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/).

Comment: @chris--- i have tried with `PHPMailer` and still doesn't find the class. I also have tried with that extension and it does not give me error but it does not send the mail. i have stunnel installed and running just in case

Comment: Watch your quoting - I think that line in your edit should be `Mailer::gmail($this->email);`. Single quotes will not result in it passing in the instance.

Comment: You're also ignoring any possible errors - I'd suggest you at least do `return $mail->send();`

Comment: @Synchro i could do such suggestion if i were able to not get the class error. i tried with other extensions that comes along with `PHPMailer` and added their debugging, most of them did not show error and some just gives error authentication, and about the quotes, it was an example. the real way i was doing it is like this `Mailer::gmail('nosthertus@hotmail.com');`

Answer (score 0):

Double check your php.ini file to make sure phpmailer is located in the include_path because other than that based on the code you provided everything looks good.

(Sorry, would have put this in the comments but I am still unable to comment just yet.)

Comment: php.ini is not needed if you are going to send emails with smtp authentication. or thats what i think

Comment: @nosthertus - Oh okay, I was just going based on the include error that you were getting. Also, as Chris mentioned above...I believe I am using the phpmailer he is referencing (which has always worked well for me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, I am using Yiis phpmailer extension for several month and it always worked very well.

However, try this with the Github thing:

```
require_once <PATH TO PHPMAILER> . 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
[...] Rest of your code here
```

Replace  with the absulute path to your `class.phpmailer.php`

Answer (score 0):

i was able to send the mail by checking on gmail history security, it was showing that someone was trying to access my account with invalid authorization, i ended up by using YiiMailer, its a bit confusing about gmail.

the code was like this:

```
$mail = new YiiMailer();
//$mail->clearLayout();//if layout is already set in config
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "account@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@strandedgrounds.sr', 'Stranded Grounds');
$mail->setSubject('Recuperacion de contraseña');
$mail->AddAddress("mail@hotmail.com");
$mail->send();
```